# Conflict with dependency 'com.google.inject:guice'

Tags: android, testing, gradle, roboguice

I am getting the following error :

Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.inject:guice'. Resolved versions for app (3.0) and test app (4.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Following is my Gradle file :

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.1'


}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/intercom/intercom-maven' }


}



android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.imagecom"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 16
    versionName "3.8"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner     "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

signingConfigs{
    release{
        storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
        storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias STORE_PASSWORD
        keyPassword STORE_PASSWORD
    }

    debug{
        storeFile file(STORE_FILE_DEBUG)
        storePassword STORE_PASSWORD_DEBUG
        keyAlias STORE_PASSWORD_DEBUG
        keyPassword STORE_PASSWORD_DEBUG
    }
}



packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    //exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "7g"

}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    sourceSets.debug.resources.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']


}
productFlavors {
    imagecom {
        applicationId "com.imagecom.imagecom"
        versionName = "7.7"
    }
    greencontrol {
        applicationId "com.imagecom.greencontrol"
        versionName = "1.0-greencontrol"
    }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    }
}



}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpcore'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile project(':bluetoothspp')
compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.+@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
compile 'me.neavo:volley:2014.12.09'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:0.7.4'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.0.+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.0.0@aar'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.5'
compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.2a'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.8'
apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.0.8'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
//Retrofit 2
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile ('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'){
    exclude module: 'asm'
}

androidTestCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
def appModuleRootFolder = '.'
def srcDir = 'src'
def googleServicesJson = 'google-services.json'

task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
from "src/debug"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
}

task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
from "src/release"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
  }

task switchToDebugGreencontrol(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
from "src/debug/greencontrol"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
}

task switchToReleaseGreencontrol(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
from "src/release/greencontrol"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
}



afterEvaluate {
processimagecomDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
processimagecomReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease
processGreencontrolDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn       switchToDebugGreencontrol
processGreencontrolReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToReleaseGreencontrol
}
```

Following is the gradle of bluetoothspp project :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    versionCode 7
    versionName "3.3"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the build.gradle of 'bluetoothspp' project?

Comment: Hi i have added the gradle for bluetoothspp also

Comment: As mentioned in the link provided in the error, two different versions of *'com.google.inject:guice'* referenced by your dependencies. I'd suggest running: '**gradlew <your_project_name>:dependencies**' to check who's dependent on it and eliminate the duplication.

Comment: I tried with that command but not working

Comment: What's the error you get? It should only print the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was with the cache which had duplicate files that was neither getting merged nor getting cleared when I press clean and rebuild the project option.

Since I had linked my project with bitbucket So I stashed it using source-tree.

Following link would be helpfull on how to Stash :
https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/stash-a-file-with-sourcetree-785332122.html

and then I Cleaned and Rebuild my project and the error was gone. That should do it for you guys too.

Thank you